Coordination Compounds
I have a doubt in a question I came across, it was to match the complexes with color.
$$\ce{List A: [Mn(H2O)6]^{2+} , [Cr(H2O)6]^{3+} , [Fe(H2O)6]^{2+} , [Sc(H2O)6]^{3+}}$$
$$\text{List B : Colorless, Green, Purple, Pink}$$
Clearly, $\ce{Sc^3+}$ has configuration $\mathrm{t_{2g}^0 e_{g}^0}$ and is therefore diamagnetic and colorless. I decided to find the complementary colors of Green, Purple, Pink which were Red, Yellowish Orange, Greenish Yellow. Then I figured out the CFSE energy for each of the remaining complexes which came to, $\mathrm{Mn^{2+}:t_{2g}^3 e_{g}^2}$, $\mathrm{Cr^{3+}:t_{2g}^3}$, $\mathrm{Fe^{2+}:t_{2g}^4 e_g^2}$, $\ce{Mn: 0}$, $\mathrm{Cr^{3+}:-1.2\Delta_{o}}$, $\mathrm{Fe^{2+}:-0.4\Delta_o}$. Which would mean Mn should have the highest wavelength of light from the three which is coming from Green, Cr should have lowest wavelength which is coming from Pink, Fe should be Purple. But the answer provided is Mn is Pink, Cr is Purple, Fe is Green, Sc is colorless.
Any help would be appreciated a lot.

We can compare and then tell the colour of a coordination compound from the options given, we can't tell them directly
The stronger ligand will split its orbital more and absorb higher energy colour and shows the complimentary colour.
In VIBGYOR moving from left to right the energy increase as E= hc/lambda
For example a ligand absorbs orange colour then it will show blue colour.
Complimentary colour of -

Violet and Indigo is Yellow
Blue is Orange
Green is Red


@MahitChopra You made a mistake. Just check how Mn2+ have highest splitting instead Cr3+ has highest splitting

Didn't I do it correctly, cr3+ does have highest splitting energy

Can you explain how ur answer is different from my doubt, all I can understand from this is the exact thing I have written.
